# How to compute R-sq for RLM?

Tags: r, lm, goodness-of-fit

I want to predict sales with lm and machine learning so I did this:

```
library("caret")
set.seed(1)
in_train <- createDataPartition(open_store$Sales, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
training <- open_store[in_train,]
testing <- open_store[-in_train,]  
total_fit <- lm(Sales ~ DayOfWeek + Promo + SchoolHoliday + StateHoliday + Month + Year + StoreType + Assortment + log(CompetitionDistance), data = training, na.action = na.omit)
summary(total_fit)
plot(total_fit$fitted.values, total_fit$residuals)
qqnorm(total_fit$residuals,  ylab = "Residual Quantiles")
total_predict <- predict(total_fit, testing)
plot(total_predict, testing$Sales)
abline(lm(total_predict~testing$Sales), col="red")
predict_eval <- lm(testing$Sales~total_predict)
summary(predict_eval)
rmse_train <- sqrt(mean(total_fit$residuals ^ 2))
rmse_test <- sqrt(mean(predict_eval$residuals ^ 2))
rmse_test/rmse_train
```

My problem is that after taking out the zeros from the initial dataset my R-sq gets really low (around 0.25) which means that my model is not good enough although my RMSE ratio is pretty good (approx. 0.99). If I leave them in the R-sq is around 0.85 but the plot looks awful. I went through some discussions and some people suggest to do my model with rlm:

```
library(MASS)    
total_fit <- rlm(Sales ~ DayOfWeek + Promo + SchoolHoliday + StateHoliday + Month + Year + StoreType + Assortment + log(CompetitionDistance), 
    data = training, 
    na.action = na.omit)
```

But it neither provides R-sq nor p values. Does anyone have a suggestion how to improve this model and how to estimate if the model performs better with lm or rlm?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe edit your question to skip the irrelevant stuff - all you need is the dataset and the rlm call.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me that `rlm` won't provide you with this info. So, you'll have to calculate it yourself.

Hmm. I Am Not A (Proper) Statistician, but something like:

```
1 - sum(residuals(total_fit)^2)/sum((testing$Sales-mean(testing$Sales))^2)
```

might do it.

Comment: Tnx but I got 2.322097 which can't be the R-sq as it's supposed to vary from 0 to 1.

May also ask if it's okay to have almost the same RMSE = 2000+ for both the model and the test if the observations are approx 1M? And if the RMSE ratio is 0.99, is it a good indicator or it just says the both the model and the test are not good? Tnx

Comment: Sounds like a q for cross validated

Comment: I find it extremely unlikely that 1 minus the ratio of two sums of squares, both of which must of course be positive, came to greater than 1. Perhaps check your code. (Or mine.)

Comment: oh yeah.. it's actually -1.32 but still not really helpful. Do you think if I take out the outliers from the initial dataset would be a good option?

Comment: Not sure. Negative R2 is possible if your prediction line is worse than a flat one through the mean. To me, this sounds as if rlm is not doing much for you.